# Creating Akka project in OSGi

Tags: scala, osgi, akka

I am hoping to run an Akka project within an OSGi container (`apache-servicemix-4.4.1-fuse-06-03`) but am having a little trouble installing the dependent libraries. I have already installed `akka-actor` and `config` as follows:

- `osgi:install -s mvn:com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor/2.1-SNAPSHOT`
- `osgi:install -s mvn:com.typesafe/config/0.4.1`

But am unable to install `scala-library` (v2.9.2 required). I have tried creating my own bundle using the `maven-bundle-plugin` but to no avail and have googled round for ages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was kindly uploaded after posting on the scala-users group:

https://github.com/guofengzh/scala-lang-osgi

Comment: Just a note - Scala 2.10.0-RC1 and beyond have OSGi support built-in, but the headers aren't built on the deployed jars by default - for now you have to download the Scala source and run a special ant target  "osgi-bundles" to get this created.  With any luck this will be added to the standard distribution shortly.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a quick workaround, use the bundle from your Scala IDE/Eclipse for Scala 2.9.2.  I did that for my Akka 2.1/Karaf POC and it worked fine.  If you don't have one, download it from [my lib folder here](https://github.com/jamie-allen/akka-osgi).

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help Jamie. Do you know how the library you suggest compares to the one Guofeng Zhang has created (see my answer)?

Comment: I do - Heiko (the creator of that lib) is my boss.  :)  That is a library to generate new bundles from Scala code, and provides a Scala language and compiler bundle from a repository.  You should definitely consider going that route assuming 2.9.2 is available.  If not, or if there is a reason you don't want to download again from an external repo, use the Eclipse one.

Comment: That is the route I have ended up going. Please let Heiko he is a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

The built binaries of [scala-lang-osgi](https://github.com/guofengzh/scala-lang-osgi) referred by @ben1729 is now available on our Bippo/Soluvas Nexus repository public repository: http://nexus.bippo.co.id/nexus/content/groups/public/

Feel free to browse our repository at http://nexus.bippo.co.id/nexus/

Usage:

```
<repository>
    <id>bippo-nexus-public</id>
    <url>http://nexus.bippo.co.id/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</repository>
```

then add one or all of them to your Maven POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-dbc</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-swing</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know when a new version comes out so I can redeploy the newer artifacts to our repo.

**Update:** [Scala OSGi 2.10-M6](https://github.com/soluvas/scala-lang-osgi) is now available on our repository:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0-M6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0-M6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-dbc</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0-M2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang-osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-swing</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0-M6</version>
</dependency>
```

It can work with Akka but using a **patched** Akka 2.1-M1 (see http://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2367-osgi-manifest-references-2-9-2 ).

The patched Akka is available in our repository as: (in Karaf URL)

`mvn:com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor/2.1-M1/jar/patch2`

Summary on Akka bug: Akka 2.1-M1 requires 2.10-M6, it doesn't work with 2.9.2 :

```
Error executing command: Error starting bundles:
nable to resolve 160.0: missing requirement [160.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=scala.collection.convert)(version>=2.9.2)(!(version>=2.10.0)))
```

But it currently imports the wrong package versions:

```
    scala.collection.convert;version="[2.9.2,2.10)",
    scala.concurrent.util;version="[2.9.2,2.10)",
    scala.concurrent.util.duration;version="[2.9.2,2.10)",
```